# Can i use MIT licensed library in my GPL3 project

Tags: mit, gpl-3, license

I'm writing a library that I want to use in my GPL3 main project and I wonder if I can license the library using the MIT license.

Comment: Are you writing the library from scratch?  How about the rest of the project?

Comment: @MadHatter the library is from scratch but the project have external libraries that are MIT licensed aswell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use an MIT-licensed library in an GPL-licensed application.

The MIT license is a permissive license that is compatible with the GPL license, so there is no problem at all.

When the library is used in the context of the GPL application, the GPL terms and conditions also apply to the library, but when the library is used independently from the GPL code, the MIT license is in full effect.

Comment: Thanks i that what i was looking for!

Comment: The MIT license states "The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software."

=> Is it really ok to just use the GPL3 license text? Or do I need to somehow replicate/copy/mention the MIT license? If so, how exactly?