# Can I use a MIT licensed library with an AGPLv3 project?

Tags: mit, agpl

I'm building a project, that is licensed under AGPLv3. I want to use a few MIT licensed C libraries, but I'm unsure if it's compatible with AGPLv3 or not.

Also, I'm not sure if the GPL-compatible licenses are also compatible with AGPL.

I want to make sure that I can use the MIT licensed libraries with my code, can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can i use MIT licensed library in my GPL3 project](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/10214/can-i-use-mit-licensed-library-in-my-gpl3-project); while I acknowledge the difference between the GPL and the AGPL, having one question for every possible license pair combination isn't going to be very helpful for future readers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All listed [GPLv3-compatible free software licenses](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.en.html#GPLCompatibleLicenses) are compatible with AGPLv3 also.

All listed [GPLv3-compatible free software licenses](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.en.html#GPLCompatibleLicenses) are compatible with LGPLv3 also, for the case of creating a derived work based on the LGPLv3-licensed work.

Comment: Is it then sufficient, to just use the AGPL license text as is? Or do I need to somehow create a combined license File or include some extra note, because MIT license states "The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software." ?